# Is there any method like onDisconnect() in firestore like there is in realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check user's online status, in realtime database I used to check this with the help of onDisconnect(), but now I've shifted to firestore and can't find any similar method in that.

Comment: If you're interested in Firestore supporting *presence detection* natively, star this issue to show Google your interest: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183581084

Comment: Uuse free unlimited FCM instead of chargeable Cloud Functions.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742584/10566281

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to this [onDisconnect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect):

> The onDisconnect class is most commonly used to manage presence in applications where it is useful to detect how many clients are connected and when other clients disconnect.

To be able to use presence in firestore, you need to connect firestore with realtime firebase(no other way).

Please check this for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Answer (score 11):

*NOTE: This solution is not especially efficient*

Off the top of my head (read: I haven't thought through the caveats), you could do something like this:

```
const fiveMinutes = 300000 // five minutes, or whatever makes sense for your app

// "maintain connection"
setInterval(() => {
  userPresenceDoc.set({ online: new Date().getTime() })
}, fiveMinutes)
```

then, on each client...

```
userPresenceDoc.onSnapshot(doc => {
  const fiveMinutesAgo = new Date().getTime() - fiveMinutes
  const isOnline = doc.data().online > fiveMinutesAgo
  setUserPresence(isOnline)
})
```

You'd probably want the code checking for presence to use an interval a little more than the interval used by the code maintaining the connection to account for network lag, etc.

**A NOTE ABOUT COST**

So, obviously, there could be significant lag between when someone disconnects and when that disconnection is recognized by other clients. You can decrease that lag time by increasing the frequency of writes to Firestore, and thus increasing your costs. Running the numbers, I came out with the following costs for different intervals, assuming a single client connection running continuously for a month:

```
Interval     Cost/User/Month
----------------------------
10m          $0.007776
 5m          $0.015552
 1m          $0.07776
10s          $0.46656
 5s          $0.93312
 1s          $4.6656
```

Going with an interval of one second is pretty pricy, at $46,656 a month for a system with 10,000 users who leave the app open all month long. An interval of 10 minutes with the same number of users would only cost $77.76 a month. A more reasonable interval of one minute, 10,000 users, and only four hours of app usage per day per user, rings in at $129.60 / month.

Comment: Nice that you added calculations! Might be worth noting that ~$5/user a month is not a lot considering they're spending 24/7 inside the app, you will _hopefully_ monetize  well on this kind of user. :P

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent.  The Firestore SDK currently doesn't have presence management like the Realtime Database SDK.

Instead, you might want to use the Realtime Database onDisconnect() in conjunction with Cloud Functions to kick off some work when the client disconnects from RTDB.  You would be assuming that that your app probably also lost its connection to Firestore at the same time.

Comment: do you have a working node.js code at least for Realtime Db? I'm using the documentation codes but they are not updating the offline changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but this method kind of hackish because we cannot use *onDisconnected* in firestore. As far as I know, realtime database use secure WebSocket technology, so thats why onDisconnected have on it

But you can use `realtime database` that can be implemented in `cloud functions`
to `update the firestore data`,

```
functions.database.ref('users/{userId}').onUpdate()
```

Somewhere in clientside:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('.info/connected')
  .on('value', async (snap) => {
    if (snap.val() === true) {
      // Update the online status in RTDB 
      await firebase.database()
        .ref(`users/${credentials.user.uid}/`)
        .set({
          online_status: true,
          start_online: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        });

      // OnDisconnect
      firebase.database()
        .ref(`users/${credentials.user.uid}/`)
        .onDisconnect()
        .set({
          online_status: false,
          last_online: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        });
    }
  });
```

in cloudfunctions (this will be trigger on update)

```
export const onUserOnlineStatusChanged = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}').onUpdate((event: functions.Change<functions.database.DataSnapshot>, context: functions.EventContext) => {
  return event.after.ref.once('value')
    .then((dataSnapshot) => dataSnapshot.val()) // Get the latest value from the Firebase Realtime database
    .then((value: any) => {
      // Update the value from RTDB to Firestore
      console.log('value.online_status', value.online_status);

      if (value.online_status == true) {
        // Set the value to the firestore
        admin.firestore()
          .collection('users_info')
          .doc(context.params.userId) // Get document by the userId / Or use .where
          .set({
            online_status: value.online_status,
            updated_at: new Date
          }, {
            mergeFields: [
              'online_status',
              'updated_at'
            ]
          });

        // Add code if necessary (when the online_status is true)

      } else if (value.online_status == false) {
        // Set the value to the firestore
        admin.firestore()
          .collection('users_info')
          .doc(context.params.userId)  // Get document by the userId / Or use .where
          .set({
            online_status: value.online_status,
            updated_at: new Date
          }, {
            mergeFields: [
              'online_status',
              'updated_at'
            ]
          });

        // Add code if necessary (when the online_status is false)
      }

    });
});
```

It would take about 1 or 2 seconds to update from cloud function to firestore

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct way to do this thing but this trick helped me achieve this disconnect listener.
 `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", async function (e) { e.preventDefault(); await firestoreRef.doc("doc-ref").update({ online: false }); });`