# How to enable offline data in firestore for web

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to enable offline data in my project.
I found the right code for this but I don't know where to implement the code

I implement the code inside the `firebaseConfig.js` file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

// firebase init
// init code goes here
var config = {
 apiKey: '',
 authDomain: '',
 databaseURL: '',
 projectId: '',
 storageBucket: '',
 messagingSenderId: ''
} 
firebase.initializeApp(config)

firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
 .then(function () {
   // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
   var db = firebase.firestore();
 })
 .catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err)
 })

 // firebase utils
 const db = firebase.firestore()
 const oldRealTimeDb = firebase.database()
 const auth = firebase.auth()
 const currentUser = auth.currentUser

 // date issue fix according to firebase
 const settings = {
   timestampsInSnapshots: true
 }
 db.settings(settings)

 // firebase collections
 const usersCollection = db.collection('users')
 const postsCollection = db.collection('posts')

export {
 db,
 auth,
 currentUser,
 postsCollection,
 usersCollection
```

}

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import {store} from './store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader 
const fb = require('./firebaseConfig.js')

Vue.config.productionTip = false

export const bus = new Vue()

Vue.use(Vuetify)

let app
fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
 if (!app) {
  app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   store,
   router,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: {
     App
   },
   render: h => h(App)
 }).$mount('#app')
}
})
```

I got this error:

[image]

Comment: If I am not mistaking, Lukas, you are using Vue.js. Can you share your main.js file (and possibly all files that are required in the main.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample code provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) suggests that you should call enablePersistence() and possibly make note if it fails for some given reason:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###',
});

firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
      }
  });
```

Subsequent queries after calling `enablePersistence()` will be internally queued until it fully completes, which means that the query may or may not be using locally cached data, depending on the result of `enablePersistence()`.  If it's important to your app to be able to use local persistence, you may wish to wait on its result (triggering on the returned promise) before performing the query.

Comment: The first answer is not technically correct because it ignores the promise returned from enablePersistence.  It makes no guarantee that the next query will make use of persistence.  Use the sample code provided in the docs to get the best possible behavior.

Comment: and how do I know that the first exmaples won't work?

Comment: Is your query that occurs immediately after calling enablePersistence() able to retrieve cached data while there is no internet connectivity?  If not, then persistence is not working.

Comment: I just talked this over with the Firestore client team.  It seems that the original code sample was misleading.  It's actually not necessary to wait on the results of the promise returned by enablePersistence() in order to make the first query.  Queries will be internally queued until enablePersistence() is fully complete.  The code sample in the docs will be updated soon.  I'll update my answer as well.

Comment: can you take a look on this one with handle online/ offline status please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768240/handle-users-online-and-offline-status-in-firebase

Comment: this tip also helped me with another issue related to multiple tabs `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence({experimentalTabSynchronization: true})`